# How to get TFDQuery to recognise when new fields are added to a TFDMemTable it is querying via TFDLocalSQL

Tags: delphi, firedac

After adding a field to an existing TFDMemTable, any TFDQuery that queries that table through a TFDLocalSQL does not recognise the new field.

The code below illustrates this: a TFDMemTable with a single field added to it in code and a TFDQuery that does a select on that table. (Assume the TFDMemTable is added to the DataSets property of the TFDLocalSQL and the TFDQuery points to the TFDConnection)  The process for adding the field to a live TFDMemTable comes from an [example project](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Berlin/en/FireDAC.TFDMemTable.Main_Sample) and the use of Unprepare, which doesn't seem to work in this case, comes from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317748/firedac-query-field-list-not-updated-after-schema-change).

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  with FDMemTable1.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef do begin
    Name := 'col1';
    DataType := ftString;
    Size := 10;
  end;
  FDMemTable1.CreateDataSet;
  FDMemTable1.Active := true;

  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM FDMemTable1';

  FDConnection1.Connected := true;
  FDLocalSQL1.Active := true;
  FDQuery1.Active := true;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  tempMT: TFDMemTable;
begin
  tempMT := TFDMemTable.Create(nil);

  try
    tempMT.Data := FDMemTable1.Data;
    FDMemTable1.Close;
    with FDMemTable1.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef do begin
      Name := 'col99';
      DataType := ftString;
      Size := 10;
    end;
    FDMemTable1.Open;
    FDMemTable1.MergeDataSet(tempMT, dmDataSet, mmNone);
    if not FDMemTable1.FieldDefs.Updated then FDMemTable1.FieldDefs.Update;
  finally
    tempMT.Free;

    FDQuery1.Active := false;
    FDQuery1.Unprepare;              // this is meant to uncache the fields
    FDQuery1.Active := true;         // Does not include 'col99' in result set
  end;
end;
```

The field is definitely added to the TFDMemTable and works fine.  Any tips on how I get the TFDQuery to recognise the new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason you are getting this behaviour is that your code is missing a step.

In the `finally` clause of your click-handler, you need to close the FDConnection, like so

```
  finally
    tempMT.Free;

    FDConnection1.Connected := False;
    FDQuery1.Active := false;
    FDQuery1.Unprepare;              // this is meant to uncache the fields
    FDQuery1.Active := true;         // Does include 'col99' in result set
    Caption := IntToStr(FDQuery1.FieldCount);
  end;
  PageControl1.ActivePage := TabSheet3;  // has FDQuery grid
```

Once you have made the above change, you should find that you get the added column in FDQuery1.  Btw, you can take out `FDQuery.Unprepare`, because it makes no difference.  `Prepare` is usually used to compile the SQL code for the query inside the back-end DB server.  In this case, the back-end server isn't involved because the FDLocalSQL1 component generates the data for FDQuery1 from the mem table.  `Unprepare` usually tells the back-end server that it can release the compiled query resources.

I think the reason your version didn't work is because of the call to
`GetActualActive` in

```
procedure TFDCustomLocalSQL.CheckActivate;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if GetActualActive and not FActivated then begin
    for i := 0 to DataSets.Count - 1 do
      DataSets.CheckUnique(DataSets[i]);
    FActivated := True;
    InternalAttachToSQL;
    for i := 0 to DataSets.Count - 1 do
      if DataSets[i].IsValid then
        InternalDataSetAdded(DataSets[i]);
  end;
end;
```

`GetActualActive` is defined as

```
function TFDCustomLocalSQL.GetActualActive: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Active and (Connection <> nil) and Connection.Connected;
end;
```

so the rest of `CheckActivate` is skipped if FDLocalSQL1 was previously active, which it was, and the FDConnection is already connected, which it is.  So, disconnecting the FDConnection allows the innards of `CheckActivate` to execute, so FDLocalSQL1 "notices" the change to the structure of FDMemTable1.

Btw, rather that code it from scratch, I based my project on this one:

D:\D10\Samples\Object Pascal\Database\FireDAC\Samples\Comp Layer\TFDLocalSQL\InMemDB

which avoided a certain amount of guesswork in how your project is set up.

Comment: Thank you. That worked though I don't understand why. I had previously tried disconnecting and reconnecting the TFDConnection which didn't work. Also I read the  CheckActivate source differently - that the TFDLocalSQL can't activate *unless* the TFDConnection is activated, which fits with the recommended sequence of activation. Thanks again